# CLion not compiling when Xcode does?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clion

I am doing a Udemy course on writing games in Unreal and learning C++ while you do. I was using CLion to write the code but when I try run it I get the following error;

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/penkin/Sandbox/penkin-unreal/Section_02/BullCowGame/cmake-build-debug --target BullCowGame -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable BullCowGame
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries()", referenced from:
      PlayGame() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [BullCowGame] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/BullCowGame.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/BullCowGame.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [BullCowGame] Error 2
```

When I create the project in Xcode it compiles and runs fine using the exact same files.

My CLion Toolchains setup;

[image]

**Files:**

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(BullCowGame)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(BullCowGame main.cpp)
```

*FBullCowGame.h*

```
#include <string>

class FBullCowGame {
public:
    void Reset();
    int GetMaxTries();
    int GetCurrentTry();
    bool IsGameWon();
    bool CheckGuessValidity(std::string);

private:
    int MyCurrentTry = 1;
    int MyMaxTries = 5;
};
```

*FBullCowGame.cpp*

```
#include "FBullCowGame.h"

void FBullCowGame::Reset() {}

int FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries() {
    return MyMaxTries;
}

int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry() {
    return MyCurrentTry;
}

bool FBullCowGame::IsGameWon() {
    return false;
}

bool FBullCowGame::CheckGuessValidity(std::string) {
    return false;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "FBullCowGame.h"

void PrintIntro();
std::string GetGuess();
void PlayGame();
bool AskToPlayAgain();

// --
// Application's entry point.
// --
int main() {
    do {
        PrintIntro();
        PlayGame();
    }
    while (AskToPlayAgain());

    return 0;  // Exit application.
}

// --
// Prints the game's intro text.
// --
void PrintIntro() {
    constexpr int WORD_LENGTH = 5;
    std::cout << "Welcome to Bulls & Cows, a fun word game." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Can you guess the " << WORD_LENGTH << " letter isogram I'm thinking of?" << std::endl;
}

// --
// Gets the string guessed by the user and returns that string.
// --
std::string GetGuess() {
    std::string Guess;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter your guess:  ";
    getline(std::cin, Guess);
    return Guess;
}

// --
// Runs through the game logic.
// --
void PlayGame() {
    std::string Guess;
    FBullCowGame BCGame;
    int MaxTries = BCGame.GetMaxTries();

    for (int count = 1; count <= MaxTries; count++) {
        Guess = GetGuess();
        std::cout << "You guessed \"" << Guess << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
}

// --
// Asks the user if they would like to play the game again.
// --
bool AskToPlayAgain() {
    std::string Response;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Would you like to play again (y/n)? ";
    getline(std::cin, Response);

    return std::tolower(Response[0]) == 'y';
}
```

Comment: It is a linking and not a compiling problem. Do you use the same cmake file to create the XCode project or did you create the XCode project manually? You need to add `FBullCowGame.cpp` to the list of sources: `add_executable(BullCowGame main.cpp FBullCowGame.cpp)`

Comment: I created a new xcode project and just used the same files minus the make stuff. Added what you suggested and it worked! Thanks so much @t.niese! So do I need to do this for every file I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a linking and not a comiling error. The error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries()", referenced from:
      PlayGame() in main.cpp.o
```

Tells you that the linker was not able to find compiled code for `FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries()` that you try to use in `PlayGame()`.

You need to add each `cpp` file you have to the list of source that has to be compiled, otherwise it won't be compiled:

```
add_executable(BullCowGame main.cpp FBullCowGame.cpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @t.niese in the comments I've sorted the problem. In the `CMakeLists.txt` I need to add my `FBullCowGame.cpp` file.

New *CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(BullCowGame)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(BullCowGame main.cpp FBullCowGame.cpp)
```